# Fullcalendar - resizing events horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fullcalendar, jquery-ui-resizable

Did someone knows a way to make events in **fullCalendar** resizable **horizontally** ??

I was searching about it but I haven't found anything.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Google calendar style, not? In that case, take a look at this project: https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar I've been using it and is very stable and active.

Comment: I started to use this FullCalendar plugin and I want to stay with it. I already customized it a lot for my own needs, but I also need events to have ability to resize horizontally.

Comment: @PawelUrban Sorry then, jquery fullcalendar doesn't have a grid system for displaying days. If you can't change of plugin, you can try to implement your desired feature using [jquery ui resizable with grid option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#snap-to-grid).

Comment: jQuery calendar has agendaWeek View and in this particular view I want to have resizable horizontally option :)

Comment: Ok. Just downloaded last version and it seems that by default it works the way you need, in the fullcalendar-1.5.3/demos/agenda-views.html file is visible.